# Como pasar mas de un argumento a variables funciones en php

Tags: php, funciones, variables

```
class Alumno{
    function mostrar($nombre,$edad){
        echo "la edad es $edad, nombre: $nombre";
    }
}

$clase="Alumno";
$func="mostrar";
$arg="juan,23";
$x=new $clase;
$x->$func($arg);
```

Solamente me llega un argumento a la función. Probé también con `call_user_func_xxxx` pero me llega con *array*, etc.. Alguien que haya echo algo de esto? 
La idea es crear objetos de manera dinamica.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *objetos de manera dinámica*? ¿Has pensando lo que pasaría si tu programa tiene varios miles de líneas de código y tienes que analizarlo, o trabajar en equipo sobre el mismo programa? ¿Alguien sabrá lo que esto significa: `$x->$func($arg);`?  ¿No estarás armando un *laberinto de programa*?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que de acuerdo a los parametros recibidos quiero que automaticamente redireccione a un controlador, al metodo correcpondiente y los argumentos necesarios. Por eso busco la generalidad. Por eso me vendria bien $obj->$metodo($args)

Answer (score 0):

Error mio:

```
call_user_func_array(array($objeto,$action_name),$valores);
```

Pasaba mal el argumento `$valores`, escribia `array($valores)`, cuando `$valores` ya era un *array*.

Answer (score 0):

lo que sucede es que le estas pasando solo un argumento, en la cual lo separas con una (,) pero igual sigue siendo uno...

```
class Alumno{
    function mostrar($nombre,$edad){
        echo "la edad es $edad, nombre: $nombre";
    }
}

$clase="Alumno";
$func="mostrar";
$arg1="juan,23";
$arg2="23";
$x=new $clase;
$x->$func($arg1, $arg2);
```

mira, asi, cuando declaras que una funcion lleva dos argumentos, en el llamado tambien le pasas los dos argumentos separados por (,)... espero te sirva... By: JJ